# error when access data from boost mapped_region

Tags: boost, out-of-memory, file-mapping

I have some trouble when visit mapped_region data.

First, I define a struct: (for stock quotes...)

```
struct bar{
double open,high,low,close;
size_t volume;
bar(double _open, double _high, double _low, double _close): open(_open),high(_high), close(_close), volume(_volume){}};
```

here is the sample.txt (I've also tried binary format) file for which I want to visit by iteration of bar type

```
89.26    89.47    89.25    89.47      563 
89.47    89.56    89.27    89.47      284 
89.46    89.56    89.26    89.33      264
```

using following code, I can read the character by character:

```
file_mapping m_file(filename,read_only); 
mapped_region region(m_file,read_only);
char const* add= static_cast<char*> (region.get_address());
```

namely, for the first data, I would get 8 9 . 2 6, character by character using add[i]. This can be terrible workload. 
**So I want to convert :**

```
bar* myaddr=(bar*)(region.get_address()), where bar is define as the above..
```

so that I can have access to data by using :

```
myaddr->open (with an offset ).
```

**For instance, now I want to visit the 3rd number in the second line, I just need:**

```
 (myaddr+1)->high
```

However, the result is really wired:

```
 e.g 1.50656e-189, or sometimes 825303072 for (myaddr+2)->volume
```

In fact, if I convert to any time beyond char , there would be such error...

Question: How can I visit mapped data by using myaddr-> without error?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a text file. If you read it as a memory mapped region you get text, not doubles. That is your problem.

Comment: So mapping from text file is not right? What format you suggest, I've tried .mat. .bin none of these work

Comment: @user3217264: Do you understand the difference between a `double` containing the value of PI and the text string "3.1415"? If not, I cannot help you.